# How to extract the value of the sibling node based on matching value of child node of another sibling node using apply-template in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

Below are my INPUT and OUTPUT XMLs. I wanted to extract the value of the sibling node "ID" if the value of child node "language" equals to "English" of another sibling node "personalInfo" using apply-template.

INPUT:
  `<customers>
    <customer>
        <ID>5345245</ID>
        <personalInfo>
            <name>John Smith</name>
            <address>123 Oak St.</address>
            <state>WA</state>
            <phone>(206) 123-4567</phone>
            <language>English</language>
        </personalInfo>
    </customer>
    <customer>
        <ID>4564545</ID>
        <personalInfo>
            <name>Zack Zwyker</name>
            <address>368 Elm St.</address>
            <state>WA</state>
            <phone>(206) 423-4537</phone>
            <language>English</language>
        </personalInfo>
    </customer>
    <customer>
        <ID>5653563</ID>
        <personalInfo>
            <name>Albert Aikens</name>
            <address>368 Elm St.</address>
            <state>WA</state>
            <phone>(206) 423-4537</phone>
            <language>spanish</language>
        </personalInfo>
    </customer>
    </customers>`

OUTPUT:
   `<customers>
    <customer>
        <ID>5345245</ID>
    </customer>
    <customer>
        <ID>4564545</ID>
    </customer>
    </customers>`

I am using below piece of code Now I have the condition mentioned above. I appreciate if anyone can help with that.

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <customers>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//*[local-name()='customer']/*[local-name()='ID']"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[local-name()='ID']">
    <customer>
    <ID>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </ID>
    </customer>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/customers">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="customer[personalInfo/language='English']">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="ID"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Unrelated to your question, but you should never have to use this kind of a hack:

```
*[local-name()='customer']
```

If your source uses namespaces, declare them in your stylesheet, assign them prefixes, and address the source nodes using the assigned prefixes.

---

### Added:

> Is there another way using like using apply-template to achieve that?

Same thing:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/customers">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="customer[personalInfo/language='English']"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="customer">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="ID"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: michael.hor257k that works and helped me with my code. I really appreciate that. Is there another way using like using apply-template to achieve that? Thanks for the tip on namespaces :)

Comment: @prashantbhavsar See the addition to my answer.